# Effect size (Cohen's d) for pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the effect size among different factor levels. To compare the two means within each factor level, the code below works fine:

```
cohens_d_list <- by(mydata, mydata$factor, function(sub) 
                       cohens_d(sub$score1, sub$score2)

                 )

cohens_d_list
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to compare each factor level for a single mean (e.g. for score1, I want to compare each factor level with each other:  factor level 1 vs. factor level 2, factor level 1 vs. factor level 3, factor level 1. vs factor level 4....) with each other. I used psych, effectsize, and effsize packages, but they don't seem to account for more than 2 levels in a single factor variable. Any suggestions for a code or package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying dozens of packages, esvis package did the trick.

```
df%>%
  ungroup(Group)%>% # Include this line if you get grouping error
coh_d(score1~ Group)
```

You get a nice table with all possible comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

You can fit a model and use the `eff_size()` function from `emmeans` (which will have the benefit of using the pooled SD from *all* groups, not just the 2 being compared):

```r
m <- lm(mpg ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars)

library(emmeans)

(em <- emmeans(m, ~ cyl))
#>  cyl emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>    4   26.7 0.972 29     24.7     28.7
#>    6   19.7 1.218 29     17.3     22.2
#>    8   15.1 0.861 29     13.3     16.9
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95

eff_size(em, sigma = sigma(m), edf = df.residual(m))
#>  contrast effect.size   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  4 - 6           2.15 0.56 29    1.003     3.29
#>  4 - 8           3.59 0.62 29    2.320     4.86
#>  6 - 8           1.44 0.50 29    0.418     2.46
#> 
#> sigma used for effect sizes: 3.223 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Why is it a benefit to use the pooled SD from all groups?

Comment: @ learners, one reason is if we assume that all independent variable groups are sampled from the same distribution (null hypothesis), then they share a variance. Like mean differences, variances are subject to sampling variability. Pooling adjusts for differences in variance, which is useful if a) you are doing a meta-analysis where different studies had different variances or b) in null hypothesis testing where your inferences are adjusted non-equal variances. In the latter case, symmetry between inferences and effect size estimates is nice :) I'm sure there are other reasons though!